# AnnotatedElementUtils error spring test

Tags: spring, testing, dependency-injection, annotations

I wrote a jUnit test but i've got an error when i execute it :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils
at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:269)
at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:257)
at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.<init>(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:326)
at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:171)
at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:621)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.<init>(DefaultTestContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:119)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 27 more
```

My configured my app like that :

[image: My app]

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("TestDao-context.xml")
public class TestDao {
@Autowired
private Dao test;


@Test
public void test() {
    Dao test = new DaoImpl();
    try {
        test.connect();
        assertTrue(true);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
}
```

my context config :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <!-- Uncomment and add your base-package here:
         <context:component-scan
            base-package="org.springframework.samples.service"/>  -->
<!-- DAO -->
    <!-- MongoFactoryBean instance -->
    <bean id="mongoFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
        <property name="port" value="27017"/>   
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoDbFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoFactoryBean" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="agence_voyage" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="dao.daoImpl.DaoImpl">
        <property name="mongoFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean> 


<!-- Services -->
    <bean id="service"
        class="service.serviceImpl.ServiceImpl">
        <property name="dao"  ref="dao"/>
    </bean>

<!-- Tests -->
    <bean id="testDao" class="testdao.TestDao">
        <property name="test" ref="dao"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

my web.xml config :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>AgenceVoyage</display-name>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The configuration seems to be good according to the different tutorials on web, but i don't know where the error comes from.

I think the TestDao-context.xml is not well implemented by my test class, because when I move the context file to another project, the error doesn't change at all.
In addition, I tested a lot of different way to configure my @ContextConfiguration and it did't change anything.

Do you see something wrong ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actual problem is inconsistency between spring-test and other spring-* jar versions (probably 3.x.x and 4.x.x are incompatible w/ each other.) Anyone could not encounter this issue can use same spring versions for all spring dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this problem all I did was update my pom configuration: 
I upgraded the version of spring-test(4.0.0.RELEASE) and JUnit.