# Spring-run Unit Tests Fail as Group, but Pass Individually

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, junit

I have several JUnit tests, all run with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.  I can run them individually, by class, from my SpringSource Tool Suite (Eclipse Juno) IDE, and they pass.  If I try to run them per-module (*"Run all tests in the selected project"*), then they fail with the following `NoClassDefFoundError` initialization error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:269)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$AnnotationDescriptor.(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils$UntypedAnnotationDescriptor.(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:326)
    at org.springframework.test.context.MetaAnnotationUtils.findAnnotationDescriptorForTypes(MetaAnnotationUtils.java:171)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:621)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.(DefaultTestContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 27 more
```

Any ideas how to resolve?  Or even troubleshoot.

Givens:

- JUnit Version 4.11
- Spring Version 3.2.9-RELEASE
- All tests use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`--others using this runner succeed individually and as the group/suite
- All tests use `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyModuleConfiguration.class })`
- All tests have `@Autowired` `@Bean`s defined in `MyModuleConfiguration`.
- [Maven Central says `AnnotatedElementUtils` is a Spring 4 class](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils), but my dependency tree shows no Spring 4 *anything*.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21181787/annotatedelementutils-error-spring-test) is similar, and he looks to have been able to resolve the issue by changing some (unclear) versions.
- **[Update 1]** `mvn test` on each module succeeds.

Comment: How about if you run maven from the command line? Maybe your IDE has another set of dependencies than the ones defined in maven.

Comment: @andrel: Updated givens: `mvn test` (from command line) succeeds.  I'll check my IDE runner's dependencies, tho, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same problem but figured out that I was using a version of spring data which depended on spring 4 dependency. I lowered down the version of spring data dependency to resolve this issue.